# Can one prove Brianchon's theorem using Ceva's theorem?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

Can I prove Brianchon's theorem using Ceva's? I am also wondering if parabola and hyperbola can be inscribed in a hexagon?

Comment: I know a method which turns a certain class of algebraic proofs (which should be applicable to Brianchon) and turns them into combinations of Ceva's and Menelaos' theorems. But I somehow doubt that this is what you have in mind. Why do you want this specific kind of proof? What suggests that it should be possible?

Comment: Instead of “inscribed into a hexagon” I guess I'd rather think about “tangent to six lines”, since the term “hexagon” suggests a finite object and the term “inscribed” suggests that the figure is completely contained in this. The “hexagon” you need for a parabola or hyperbola has to contain some points at infinity, so it's a projective hexagon but perhaps not an intuitive one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof in Hatton's [Projective Geometry](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n205/mode/2up) (lower right hand of pg 191).

One way to do this is study the proof of Pascal's Theorem using Menelaus' Theorem (e.g. [here](http://mathgardenblog.blogspot.com/2013/08/hexagrammum-mysticum2.html)) and then dualize it.  The final step uses a dual version of Carnot's theorem, which is discussed in the Hatton reference.

Also see Exercises 159-162 of Smith's [Modern Geometry](https://archive.org/details/introductorymod00smitgoog/page/n291/mode/1up).

Comment: Nice sources linked!